# Showing $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I am attempting to show that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

As of now, I have managed to show that (1) $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,1]$ for any $a \in (0,1)$. Furthermore, I have shown that (2) $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}=1$.

I am now unsure how to proceed. Intuitively, I feel like the result should follow form (1) and (2) above. I am struggling however to prove rigorously that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

I would just like to add that my knowledge of Riemann integration is quite basic. Essentially, I've only been given the following definition, for a function $f$ on $[a,b]$: $f$ is Riemann integrable iff $U(f)=L(f)$, where $U(f)=\inf\{\int_{a}^{b}{\phi}:\phi\in S[a,b], \phi\geq f\}$ and $L(f)=\sup\{\int_{a}^{b}{\phi}:\phi\in S[a,b], \phi\leq f\}$. I also know that regulated functions are Riemann integrable.

Comment: can you express $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ as a Maclauren series?

Comment: if $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1]$ and has a limit as $x \to 0$ then..

Comment: You can prove that $\sin(x)/x$ is continuous on $[1/n,1] \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: It is not a Riemann integral.

Comment: You need to be precise. It's not defined on $[0,1]$ so it's not Riemann integrable there. On the other hand, if you define it as $1$ at $x=0$, then it's continuous so the result is trivial. If you define it as some other value at $x=0$, use the fact that functions w/ finitely many removable discontinuities are integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ for  $x\in (0,1] $.

$\int_0^1f$ is an improper integral which is convergent since the function $f$ has a limit at $0^+$.

If we define $g$ by

$$g(x)=f(x) \text{ if } x\ne 0$$
and
$$g(0)=\lim_{0^+}f(x)=1$$

$g $ is then Riemann integrable at $[0,1]$ cause it is continuous at $[0,1]$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Define $$g(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{c c} 
\frac{\sin(x)}{x} & \mbox{ if } x \neq 0 \\
1 & \mbox{ if } x=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

Prove that $g(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and hence Riemann Integarble.

Compare the Riemann Sums of $f$ and $g$...

Answer (score 0):

A simple and quick way to show that the function is Riemann integerable, is that it is bounded and continuous *almost* everywhere. Any function on a compact interval is bounded by the EVT, and in this case, the function is clearly continuous everywhere, so its continuous a.e, so it is Riemann integerable.